Real TurtleBot hardware implementation did not use catkin_make
The doubt I have pertains to the procedure for running ROS nodes. I followed this tutorial series and learned about using catkin_make to run the ROS node. However, in a real hardware implementation, I reviewed this tutorial. According to the second tutorial, catkin_make isn't necessary, yet the TurtleBot moves well.
I would like to know the reason behind it. Any help will be appreciated.
